# Adding plus 1 towards an array containing full of number via main class and another class

Tags: java

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
   public static void main(String[] args)                                       
   {                                        
      int[] num = {1,2,3,4};                                        
      System.out.println(Counter.add(num));                                     
   }                                        
}
```

Class

```
public class Counter                                        
{                                       
   public static int add(int[] numb)                                        
   {                                        
     for(int i=0;i<numb.length;i++){                                        
        numb[i]++;                                      
        System.out.println(numb[i]);                                        
        int result = result + numb[i];                                      
     }                                      
     return result;                                     
   }                                        
}
```

I am trying to output the total number in the array list, but with a twist, having `+1` to each number in the array list, so `1,2,3,4` would give me `14`, as `1+2+3+4 = 10 + 4` (+1 to each number), do I have to use .split to give me the total amount of variable in the array to add onto the total addition?

Comment: You declare `result` within the for loop, so it is only in scope within the loop

Comment: When you get an error message, you absolutely need to read it, carefully. Analyze it. Extract its meaning. Google it. Post it if you really don't understand it. Don't ignore it. Error messages exist for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to use .split to give me the total amount of variable in the array to add onto the total addition?

No. You can simply return the sum, plus the length of the `Array`. Also you declare result within the for loop, so it is only in scope within the loop. Move it outside of the loop

```
public static int add(int[] numb)                                     
{         
   int result = 0;                            
   for(int i=0;i<numb.length;i++){
      System.out.println(numb[i]);                                      
      result += numb[i];                                        
   }                                       
   return result + numb.length;                                      
}
```

Which, when called with the `Array` `int[] num = {1,2,3,4};` outputs `14`.